# STEAM isnt starting >>

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam

How can i fix this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: Do you have an Nvidia GPU driver?

Comment: The better question: Which driver do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You must install the `nvidia` drivers on your PC,if you have a modern GPU open terminal and run these commands for the latest driver,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

If you have an older GPU it may not support this driver, in this case you can use the `additional drivers` application preinstalled in Ubuntu to find the right one for you.

You MUST use the proprietary driver to use Steam.

Comment: As you are a rep 1 user, if this helps you, say thanks and let others know this worked, by clicking the check mark on the left.

Comment: AFAIK newest drivers won't work if you have an older nVidia card; in such case accept the suggested drivers versions form Ubuntu's "Additional Drivers"

Comment: @madneon Thats a good point, I will update to reflect this.